# AVPlayer play continuously

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an array of object. Each object has a property url. Using this url I am playing audio on `AVPlayer`.

```
func playAudio(url: URL)
    {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url )
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true)
        {
            do
            {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            }
            catch _ as NSError {

            }

            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CourseDetailViewController.moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    }
```

I want to play the audios of all objects continuously. For which I have set

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CourseDetailViewController.moviePlayBackDidFinish(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

In `CourseDetailViewController.moviePlayBackDidFinish` I am again calling playAudio. I then took player as a global variable so that it is not initialised again. But there is no overload of `AVPlayer` where we can supply url to already existing `AVPlayer`. And if do `let player = AVPlayer(url: url )` for next audio, it doesn't play because the previous AVPlayer instance is in the foreground.
This is the challenge I am facing in playing continuous audios. I would appreciate if there a better and neat way to do this.

Comment: You don’t need to nest those `try` statements. You can put them both into one `do` block.

Comment: There is an AVPlayerQueue object which I think you will need. Google it.

Comment: @Fogmeister : Agree. Changed the code. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390806-replacecurrentitemwithplayeritem

Use this method

Comment: Another note. If you’re not doing anything with those errors you can just do `try? ThingThatThrows` and you don’t need the do catch blocks at all. 

Comment: how about using `AVQueuePlayer` to set up all audios?

Comment: @Fogmeister, Tony : Thanks to you both. However in this context replaceCurrentItem is proving to be of more help. It's not that AVQueuePlayer won't work but with replaceCurrentItem, equation has become much easy.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same in AVPlayer, but playing video continuously. I hope you can solve this issue exactly the same way. Add an observer to check if the player reached at the end of item. When ever each item reached at the end, notification will call.

- Adding observer:

  ```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                         selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                         name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                         object: avPlayer.currentItem)
  avPlayer.play()
  ```
- Notification method:

  `func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification){
      //TODO: Add your code here..
  }`

Comment: Thanks Anas. The code which you have suggested, I am already doing that. The issue I am(was) facing is after the above code which I am now able to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at `AVQueuePlayer`. This player is used to play a number of items in sequence. [SDK Docs at link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer)